# PyCharm reindexing when project is stored on a NAS

Tags: python, pycharm, nas

I have been working with PyCharm for quite some time now and I recently upgraded my storing system with a NAS.

Everything is working fine except one : PyCharm scans through my files to reindex them very very often. This makes me losing a lot of time waiting for it to end.

When the reindexing occurs:

- When a script ends
- When a debugging session ends
- When PyCharm loses the focus, i.e. I use another application

So it happens basically ALL the time, taking quite a long time (several minutes sometimes).

Misc.:

- Windows 10
- PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1
- Netgear - ReadyNas 422

Do you have any ideas to solve this issues ?

Answer (score 3):

So I have contacted the IntelliJ support and here is their response:

> Working with network drives/folders is not supported officially yet.
>   Using remote development features is recommended (remote interpreter,
>   deployment etc). Here is more detailed answer
>   https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207069145/comments/207464249.

What I end up doing, which is really not ideal, is to create a local copy of my projects environment and syncing it with a folder in my NAS. To do so I used the SyncBackPro software.

Comment: You can [vote here for the corresponding feature request for PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm both at home and at work with code stored on a Samba share (using its remote interpreter feature). I don't encounter consistent reindexing but by default it does not support file system notifications to know when a file changed.

However, as a programmer this shouldn't discourage you! You can drop in your own file system notifier that connects to your remote system (assuming your NAS runs Linux and supports SSH) and thus avoid the performance drop.

I actually wrote such a proxy to run the fsnotifier on a remote system a few years ago and I'm still using it. If you are interested, check out https://github.com/ThiefMaster/fsnotifier-remote

Some things in the repo are outdated (JetBrains removed this stupid file size check for example), but it should still provide you a good basis to start from if you are interested in using it.

Comment: Interesting, I will definitely look into it !